# Handsontable fixed table bug

Tags: javascript, css, handsontable

I'm trying to make a Handsontable grid table for a fixed table with multiline headers to avoid the horizontal scrolling.

I made it using two ways : Using max-width in the css file or using fixed columns.
But in both solution manualColumnMove doesn't work as expected for example:

```
 [code]: http://jsfiddle.net/bounmed/mua144zv/
```

I can't move the first column to the end.
and if i move columns a lot it get missed up.